# React styled-component

Tags: reactjs, typescript, styled-components

I'm reading the `styled-components` documentation but there was a thing that was not explained in the documentation, below is the code example:

```
const Button = styled.button<{ $primary?: boolean; }>`
  background: ${props => props.$primary ? "#BF4F74" : "white"};
  color: ${props => props.$primary ? "white" : "#BF4F74"};

  font-size: 1em;
  margin: 1em;
  padding: 0.25em 1em;
  border: 2px solid #BF4F74;
  border-radius: 3px;
`;
```

What does this code mean: `<{ $primary?: boolean; }>`? Because this syntax isn't explained in styled component docs.

Answer (score 1):

This is a type information for typescript.

This means that a prop called `$primary`, having boolean type and is optional.

Answer (score 1):

> What does this code mean: `<{ $primary?: boolean; }>`? Because this syntax
> isn't explained in styled component docs.

It is actually explained in a bit of detail in the [Typescript](https://styled-components.com/docs/api#typescript) section of the API page. See specifically [Using Custom Props](https://styled-components.com/docs/api#using-custom-props).

> ```
> import styled from 'styled-components';
> import Header from './Header';
>
>
> const NewHeader = styled(Header)<{ customColor: string }>`
>   color: ${(props) => props.customColor};
> `;
> ```

### Syntax/Code Breakdown

```
<{ $primary?: boolean; }>
   abbbbbbbc: ddddddd
```

This is declaring a custom prop with the following breakdown:

- a. `"$"` prefix indicates a [transient prop](https://styled-components.com/docs/api#transient-props), e.g. a prop that isn't passed to the underlying React node or rendered to the DOM element
- ab. Prop name, e.g. `customColor` or `$primary`
- c. Prop is optional
- d. Prop is a boolean type

Answer (score 0):

I'm not super familiar with styled-components, but the code you're mentioning gives the button a prop called `$primary`. The `: boolean` indicates that the prop is a boolean, so it could be `true` or `false`. (If you're not familiar with props and components in frameworks like react, check out the [documentation here](https://react.dev/learn/passing-props-to-a-component).) To explain in simple terms, a prop is an input for a component, like a parameter for a function. The component's display or behavior/functionality may change in response to a prop.